# What is Tabs in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutableattributedstring

Could someone please tell me what is Tabs when we do a `po` on an mutable attributed string ?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the log you see that the tabs are related to `NSParagraphStyle` which has a `tabStops` property.

> The NSTextTab objects, sorted by location, that define the tab stops for the paragraph style.

Answer (score 1):

They are the tab stops set in the string's associated paragraph style. See `NSParagraphStyle`.